# Prerequistes knowledge of doing RCP projects

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-scout

I have done .NET Win32 projects and from Java well I can adopt my knowledge to its classes and you know the language itself but as far as technologies based on Java ..for example I mean SWT?, JFace,Hibernate, etc... I have zero experience with them...

Now by two weeks! I need to create a DEMO application with RCP,Eclipse ..a simple one tho, just some forms with a couple of ListViews and SpreadSheets on them, type something in a ComboBox, add it to a spreadsheet, etc.. stuff like this.

Ok, with this background and what I need to know, please let me know what is my starting point? any books? resources? and prerequisite knowledge that I need to learn first?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with [Lars Vogel's pile of excellent tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html).  They're broken out into basic categories, and if you work your way through several of them you should be able to start getting a feel for things.

Answer (score 1):

may i suggest to have a look at eclipse scout [1]. the framework comes with the scout sdk which should helpt you do what you're looking for.

understanding of the eclipse platform is initially not required. however, a good understanding of java is ...

after the "hello world" you can go through the more comprehensive demo app [2]. should you hit a roadblock don't hesitate to ask questions in our forum [3].

good luck! matthias

```
[1] http://www.eclipse.org/scout
[2] http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Tutorial/3.8
[3] http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=174
```